# reconocer minúscula o mayúscula

Tags: python

Quisiera consulta qué se debe hacer para que cuando escriba "ejecutivo o Ejecutivo o EJECUTIVO" con distinto tipo de letra me lo acepte y no que me arroje un error si escribo distinto. Espero haberme explicado.

Les dejo el código

```
cargo=str(input("escribe tu cargo: "))
def sueldo(cargo):
    dinero=0
if cargo=="Ejecutivo" or "ejecutivo":
    dinero=9000
elif cargo=="Jefe" or "jefe":
    dinero=1000
elif cargo==f"Externo" or "externo":
    dinero=5000
```

print( "tu sueldo para el", (cargo), "es de ", (dinero))

Comment: Convierte la cadena en minusculas y compara el resultado con la version en minusculas de la palabra. Una cadena se pasa a minuscula con cadena.lower()

Comment: `input()` devuelve un string; apllcarle `str()` es innecesario.

Comment: No olvides darle formato también al `print` en la pregunta... Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio (así además obtienes tu primera [medalla](/help/badges)).

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos se usa transformar todo a minúsculas antes de usar lo tipeado. De esa manera simplificas toda la operación posterior:

```
cargo = input("escribe tu cargo: ").lower()
```

Dado que `input()` devuelve una cadena, no necesitas usar `str()`.

La función `sueldo()` necesita retornar un valor. La variable `dinero` es interna a la función y desaparece al retornar. Si quieres usar su valor fuera de la función, tienes que hacer `return dinero`.

Ya que tienes el cargo, tienes que llamar a la función para obtener el sueldo.

Todo arreglado queda en

```
def sueldo(cargo):
    if cargo == "ejecutivo":
        dinero=9000
    elif cargo == "jefe":
        dinero=1000
    elif cargo == "externo":
        dinero=5000
    else:
        dinero=1000
    return dinero

cargo= input("escribe tu cargo: ").lower()
print( "tu sueldo para el", cargo, "es de ", sueldo(cargo))
```

produce

```
escribe tu cargo: jefe
tu sueldo para el jefe es de  1000

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda...,te pasaste

Comment: Agradécele [aceptando](/help/accepted-answer) su respuesta @OmarMedina.